# tomcat published two projects under path "webapps/"

Tags: shell, tomcat, tomcat7, sh

I modified the file conf/server.xml like this below

```
  <Context path="AA" docBase="BB" reloadable="true" />
```

when I start tomcat  from a shell file publish.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#defined
TOMCAT_HOME="/root/software/apache-tomcat-7.0.29"

#start tomcat
cd "$TOMCAT_HOME"/bin
sh startup.sh
echo "tomcat is starting,please try to access $PROJECT console url"
```

tomcat publish two projects under path "webapps/",AA and BB。And I tracked that BB  was published after AA.

If you logged on the  terminal , and start tomcat directly in the directory  "$TOMCAT_HOME"/bin with command:

```
>./startup.sh
```

Only one project "BB" under path "webapps/"。

Who can tell me Why?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have double-deployed your web application.

How? Well, you put `BB.war` into `webapps/` (which will be auto-deployed to `/BB`) and then you put `<Context path="AA" docbase="BB">` into `server.xml` which deployed `BB.war` to `/AA`. What did you expect?

If you just want your application to be deployed to `/AA`, then just re-name the WAR file to `AA.war` and be done with it: take-out the `<Context>` in server.xml because it's just making your job harder. This is why it's [explicitly recommended not to do that](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and I think I have to follow that way finally. But I just want to know the answer that why started the server  the same ways produced different results.